# Is there a way to set a custom view's size for a Scene with a percentage of the screen's size?

Tags: android, android-layout, width, android-view, android-transitions

My goal is to set a custom `Transition` between two `Scene`s objects. The problem is that my ending scene contains a view that should have a specific width (80% of the screen width).

I am aware about the `layout_weight` for children of `LinearLayout` for instance, but i am looking for something which always works & does not require all children to carry a weight attribute.

The `ChangeBounds()` transition attribute will only resize starting scene's xml views to match the ending scene's xml value of the same view if it changed.

(I have tried with `ValueAnimator` objects which works perfectly but are absolutely not smooth and that's why i am using `Transition`s.)

Answer (score 0):

Getting screen sizein pixels is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1016941/6410957). Then, you can set view layout parameters like width and height or positions according to your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, i am already doing this inside my app, but my question is about a Scene objects which relies on xml files and target views. 
I have a custom ```Transition``` such as https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/custom-transitions